# Reduction formula question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given that $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^n\cos x\,dx$, show that $I_n=(\frac {\pi}{2})^n - n(n-1)I_{n-2}$. 
I wrote $x^n$ as $xx^{n-1}$ and then used the by parts formula twice and then once again on one of the terms. I got $I_{n-2}$ in the process but could not get the given result. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}x^n \cos x \,dx &= \left.\vphantom{\frac 1 1}\sin x x^n\right|^{\pi/2}_0 - n\int_0^{\pi/2}x^{n-1}\sin x \,dx \\
&= \left.\vphantom{\frac 1 1}\sin x x^n\right|^{\pi/2}_0 + \left.\vphantom{\frac 1 1}n x^{n-1}\cos x\right|^{\pi/2}_0 - n(n-1) \int_0^{\pi/2}x^{n-2}\cos x \, dx\\
& = \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n - n(n-1) \int_0^{\pi/2}x^{n-2}\cos x \,dx
\end{align}

Comment: I don't follow your working. What did you do? What was your motivation?

Comment: @user140161 Firstly I used $\cos x dx = d\sin x$ and integration by part, then I used $\sin x dx = -d \cos x$ and again integration by part

Comment: how do these substitutions help?

Comment: @user140161 as I showed, these substitutions lead to the desired result. What is not clear?

Comment: I get the substitutions but i'm just a little confused because i've never used such substitutions in integration problems. What made you think you should use both of these substitutions? If we don't use them, will we still get the desired result?

Comment: @user140161 In fact I used exactly the same thing as in the answer that you've accepted. Maybe it's the way that I write the substitutions which causes confusion?

Comment: that was confusing a little confusing too, yeah. Can you answer my questions?

Comment: @user140161 If it's the first time we meet this kind of problem, we don't know what should be the right way, so we can make some trials. There are not too many easy options, we can choose either to put $\sin x$ after $dx$ or to put $x^n$ after $dx$. But since the second way doesn't work and the first works...

Comment: I'm just asking, will we get the desired results if we don't use the substitutions?

Comment: @user140161 for your last question, I don't know how to get the results using integration by parts if we don't use these substitutions

Comment: I tried this question again. I was able to get the desired result without using these substitutions. However the working was long and tedious; I had to use the by parts formula thrice. Could you recommend an online resource that I could use to get familiar with these kind of substitutions?

Comment: @user140161 Sorry, I am not aware of one particular good online resource about that. But if you google "exercise integration by parts", you can find several links. And maybe you can also go through related questions on this site

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}I_n&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^n(\sin x)'dx\\&=[x^n\sin x]_{0}^{\pi/2}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}nx^{n-1}(-\sin x)dx\\&=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n+n\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n-1}(\cos x)'dx\\&=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n+n[x^{n-1}\cos x]_{0}^{\pi/2}-n\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(n-1)x^{n-2}\cos xdx\\&=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n-n(n-1)I_{n-2}.\end{align}$$